# How to accelerate CNN training using fit generator

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 60000 images which I split in train and validation set (80/20) and I use `ImageDataGenerator` to get the images from disk as batches of size 32. I am dealing with a multi-label classification task with 6000 classes (labels). In order to tackle this problem I am using the following CNN using Keras:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_27 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_27 (MaxPooling (None, 128, 128, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_28 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_28 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 64, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_29 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_29 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 32, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 131072)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 512)               67109376  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 5216)              2675808   
=================================================================
Total params: 70,008,416
Trainable params: 70,008,416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I am using `fit_generator` to train the model and `steps_per_epoch = total_training_samples/batch_size`. However it takes way too long (more than a week) to be trained for 10 epochs and it is a quite simple model. I tried to make the architecture even simpler by reducing the number of layers and neurons but the train time was also too much and the results was bad. I know that the last decision layer (with 5216 neurons) is responsible for the huge number of parameters. What else could I change to make the model more feasible to be trained?

Comment: Takes one week in what hardware? Are you using a GPU?

Comment: No, just an 8 core CPU

Comment: That's why it is slow, use a GPU.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a very old one which has not CUDA support.

Comment: Then the only thing you could do is to increase the batch size.